# Remote validation, value not getting to validation controller

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I am trying MVC3 remote validation for the first time.  i using it for the classic 'is that user name taken' scenario, and i am failing.  I have checked the ajax info in chrome developer and it looks like it sending the value, but at my validation controller, the string is null.

From the ajax header (in the google developer):

```
UserData.login:jon
```

the validation controller:

```
public class ValidationController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Validation/

    public JsonResult IsUsernameAvailable(string login)
    {
        var repo = new Repository();

        bool IsNameInUse = repo.CheckUserName(login);

        if (IsNameInUse == true)
        {
            return Json("The Username has been taken, please try another", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

}
```

the 'CheckUserName' method:

```
    public bool CheckUserName(string Username)
    {
        var existingUser = (from u in db.useraccount
                           where u.login.Equals(Username)
                           select u).SingleOrDefault();

        if (existingUser == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

and the user model has the Remote attribute on it:

```
    [Remote("IsUserNameAvailable", "Validation")]
    [Display(Name = "Choose a Login Name")]
    [StringLength(40)]
    [Required]
    public string login { get; set; }
```

i have read some stuff about manually binding in the validation controller, but the examples I use to build this did not mention anything about that, so i am assuming manual binding would just be a patch to something I have done wrong.  Let me know if you need any other data.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the problem.  As seen in the ajax being sent, the field is sending UserData.login, but the parameter for the validation controller is just login.  They need to match, so that is solved.

I guess now I need to change my viewmodel a bit.